# aws Fsx cross region replication

Tags: amazon-web-services, disaster-recovery, aws-vpc-peering, amazon-fsx

Is there any way to replicate aws fsx data cross-region without using was datasync agent. the datasync has minimal time scheduling as 1 hour. But for aggressive RTO for less than 1 hour this won't help.
Any workaround solution? can the data be replicated directly on was fsx if we have vpc peering transit gateway between two regions?

Comment: posted a solution, did it help?

Answer (score 0):

> Any workaround solution?

Yes you can Use AWS Backup to copy data between 2 regions
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/using-backups.html#aws-backup-and-fsx